# Update variable inside Socket.IO callback

Tags: javascript

How could **this._arr** array be updated inside a socket.io callback?

```
class SocketClass{

 constructor(server) {
    this._arr = [];
    this._io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    this._initListeners();
 }

 _initListeners() {
    this._io.on('connection', (socket, arr) => { 
        socket.on('event1', (data) => {
            this._arr.push(data);
        });

    });
 }

}
```

The problem is that **this._arr** is ***undefined*** inside a callback. I suppose it's because **this** is referencing to callback function itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`How could be this._arr array updated inside a socket.io callback?`

The easiest way I do this, is by capturing scope of the object, using the `that = this` coding style..

ps. Although arrow function are used to keep scope, I still think `that = this` is easier and more flexible in the long run.. as you could do things more specific too. eg..  `thisSocketClass`,  `thisEvent`  etc..

eg..

```
class SocketClass{

 constructor(server) {
    this._arr = [];
    this._io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    this._initListeners();
 }

 _initListeners() {
    const that = this;
    this._io.on('connection', (socket, arr) => { 
        socket.on('event1', (data) => {
            that._arr.push(data);
        });    
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But is it possible to pass that._arr to other function so it could be modified there?

Comment: Yes, you can pass either `that` or `that._arr` without problems.

Comment: tried add "update(that);" inside callback and after it runs _arr didn't change. Event though inside "update" function it successfully update. Maybe using 'bind' the only option there?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to tell.  But if you sent `that` to another function and changed `_arr` it certainly should change `_arr`, your maybe getting an async issue here.  `Maybe using 'bind' the only option there`  No,

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but you can just push items in your array and it will update.

```
let arr = [];
io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
    socket.on('event1', (data) => {
        if(data) {
            arr.push(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry, my bad! I was trying to simplify code as mich as possible. Now it's more relevant. Could you please take a look?

Comment: It's basically the same thing, if that does not work for you please explain why and give us errors to work with!